# Rails - How to query database by date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

This sounds incredibly simple, but I can't get it to work(rails newbie).

What I want to do is use `FooModel.find(:all, :order => 'date')`. Yet this does not work(throws an error). Why is this?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Hey @TehEpicPineapple, I see your question has been answered, but just FYI what you have will work in Rails 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Foo.order("date")       # Ascending (oldest first) by default

Foo.order("date DESC")  # Descending (newest first)

Foo.where(type: "bar").order("date DESC").limit(10)
# Get the 10 newest Foo of type "bar".

Foo.where(type: "bar").order("date DESC").limit(10).to_sql
# SELECT "foos".* FROM "foos"  
# WHERE "foos"."type" = 'bar' 
# ORDER BY date DESC 
# LIMIT 10
```

Check this guide out: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

Comment: Appreciate it! Will accept the answer as soon as SO will let me